# What would be an MS Access query to return all the results from one table and a yes/no if it's in another table

Tags: ms-access

What would be a query in Access where I can return everything from table1 (hosts) and an additional column. That column would be a yes or a no, if that host exists in table 2?

```
Table 1:  Name: hosts               Fields: Hostname, IP address, OS           
Table 2:  Name: Current             Fields: Hostname
```

I think this should be easy, but I'm banging my head into the wall, due to knowledge or lack thereof. I don't want add another field to table 1. I did see some solutions that did that.  Periodically, I'm going to blow away table 2 with a new set of hosts and rerun the query.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on given info, this is simple. Build query joining tables and calculate a field that returns true/false.

```
SELECT Hosts.*, Not IsNull([Current].[Hostname]) AS InCurrent
FROM [Current] RIGHT JOIN Hosts ON Current.Hostname = Hosts.Hostname;
```

Or

```
SELECT Hosts.*, Not IsNull([Current].[Hostname]) AS InCurrent
FROM Hosts LEFT JOIN [Current] ON Hosts.Hostname = Current.Hostname;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I figured it was easy, but I only need to dabble in queries once a year or so..  I added an iif statement to convert it to a yes/no..

Comment: SELECT Hosts.*, iif(Not IsNull([Current].[Hostname])=0,'No','Yes') AS INCurrent
FROM [Current_] RIGHT JOIN Hosts ON Current.Hostname = Hosts.Hostname;